# How can I fix my theme header for my CSS stylesheet?

Tags: theme-development, themes, child-theme, css

```
/*
 Theme Name:     Its Bullish
 Theme URI:      https://www.itsbullish.com
 Description:    Its Bullish
 Author:         Bullish Advertising
 Author URI:     https://itsbullish.com
 Template:       Divi
 Version:        1.0.0
*/
```

WordPress keeps returning an error message that the stylesheet is missing a valid theme header. Any insight will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :D

Please put it in style.css inside your theme directory.

```
/*
Theme Name: Its Bullish
Theme URI: https://www.itsbullish.com
Description: Its Bullish 
Author: Bullish Advertising
Author URI: https://itsbullish.com
Template:     Divi
Version:      1.0.0
Text Domain:  divi-child
*/
```

Comment: I did as you said and Wordpress returned this error, "The theme is missing the index.php file." It is a child theme is this required?

Comment: @Zack I have updated the code for child theme :D

Comment: @Zack Please upvote for me :D

Comment: @Zack Please help me by way accepted this my answer :D ( Don't vote this comment :D)

Comment: Wang, please upvote me so I can. Stackoverflow is saying that I need at least a 15 ranking to upvote because I am new.